# Why the ModelState does not return error messages for datatypes other than strings?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is a snapshot of my `ViewModel` (VM) which matches my entity model. in my controller I handle validation by adding `ModelState` error messages using `ModelState.AddModelError` and then I return all error messages using a static method, `FormatErrorResponse`.

**My problem** is if the property is anything other than `string`, the error message is always empty! in the below VM `AreaCode` is `int`, if I change it to `string` I get the error message but not the other way around,

What am I missing here?

this is my VM,

```
public class SaveViewModel {
     public int AreaCode { get; set; }
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
     public string GenderId { get; set; }
}
```

and my `FormatErrorResponse`,

```
public static object FormatErrorResponse (ModelStateDictionary modelState) {
            var errors = new List<string> ();
            foreach (var state in modelState) {
                foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors) {
                    errors.Add (error.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            var response = new { errorMessages = errors };
            return response;
        }
```

in my `API` controller,

```
bool isValidPhoneNumber = this.applicationUserRepository.isValidPhoneNumber (patientUser);
     if (!isValidPhoneNumber) {
       ModelState.AddModelError (string.Empty, "Invalid phone number!");
       return StatusCode (400, StaticHandlers.FormatErrorResponse (ModelState));
      }
```

Comment: can you add a breakpoint on `return StatusCode` and check if it is added into the model state in both cases

Comment: you have not used `AreaCode` on your `FormatErrorResponse`. How are you getting `isValidPhoneNumber`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, `isValidPhoneNumber` is a method that returns `boolean`, I updated the post

Comment: try checking your boolean value in the debugger. or use a logger inside the if block

Comment: a quick question - instead of displaying field error, why you always want to display generic error? If you defined the Key like ` ModelState.AddModelError ("PhoneNumber", "Invalid phone number!");` then the validation message is displayed for the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here is the `ModelState` itself, I have the following code in the beginning of my method,

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return StatusCode (400, StaticHandlers.FormatErrorResponse (ModelState));
        };
```

There was a conflict between my `JSON` `datatype` and my VM representation.
I am providing a `string` in my `JSON` and my VM was expecting an `int`.

this [post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2064126.aspx?Data%20Annotations%20error%20message%20not%20displayed) explain the issue too.